# HTML5 Audio addEventListener

Tags: html, audio, addeventlistener

can someone know where to find the event listener list for HTML5 audio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find them at the w3school website listed under the **Media Events** [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)! Next time try to google these things. Its far easier than to clutter the community with questions that a simple search would have accomplished.

To add an event listener to audio element just simpy do this

```
var audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.src = "audio/sample.mp3";
audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function () {
 alert('The file is loaded and ready to play!');
}, false);
```

instead of `canplaythrough` you can use all of the media events i posted above from W3.

Comment: the url you sent me is for the event attributes am searching for the listeners

Comment: That's *not* a W3 website. It's the w3schools website, a completely different organisation (that, some would say, preys on this very confusion)

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/ Don't confuse the two like @BobbyJack said, they are very different.

Comment: Events to Listen To:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events